# How to delete many-to-many relations in yii2 (pivot table)

Tags: eloquent, yii2

I have the relation declared using ActiveRecord->hasMany()

```
public function getChildren()
{
    return $this->hasMany(File::class, ['id' => 'child_file_id'])
        ->viaTable('file_image_list', ['parent_file_id' => 'id']);
}
```

I can get related models, but i dont know how to delete relations (not models).

Is Yii2 have something like `associate` or `sync` in Eloquent?

Can i do something like `$file->children->delete()` without loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have junction table `file_image_list` and you do not want to delete the `File` models, you probably want to use `unlinkAll()` method of `BaseActiveRecord` class.
If will only nullify/destroy the record from your mapping table (`file_image_list`), moreover you don't have to use loop for objects children.

I believe this is what you need:

```
/** @see File::getChildren() */
$file->unlinkAll('children', true);
```

Pay attention that `unlinkAll(name, delete)` method has two parameters:

1. name - is the relation name. (I wrote @see phpdoc above in order to make it possible to find usages on that relation, if you decide to change/refactor it one day)
2. delete - whether to delete the record in the junction table. If set to `false` it will just nullify foreign key from that table (so make sure that column is nullable)

Comment: Thanks, it helps me!